# Contenido no seguro bloqueado. Error Chrome al usar SSL con Cloudflare

Tags: seguridad

Estoy usando Cloudflare para acelerar mi sitio web y tener un certificado SSL gratis para mi dominio.
Todo está bien con la página de mi dominio principal, pero hoy he creado un subdominio para instalar en él WordPress, y resulta que después de añadirlo en la lista de DNS de Cloudflare, ya no carga los estilos (se ve solo el HTML).

Chrome me muestra en la barra de direcciones a la derecha una alerta que dice "Contenido no seguro bloqueado", y así es.

He comprobado que el error no puede venir por usar HTTPS y cargar documentos con HTTP, porque WordPress lo hace bien y usa //dominio.com/ejemplo para cargar todo.

¿Qué podría ser?

Answer (score 0):

es probable que el error se solucione, colocando el ssl como flexible y agregando la siguiente regla en el panel de cloudflare.

```
http://*tusitio.com/*
```

always use https

Comment: Revisa [answer].